# How does one make a method with an Iterable return type in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, iterable

So I am new to coding. I've done web design and smaller projects but they were mostly straightforward. My friend referred me to try asking questions here on Stack Overflow.

[I recently came across the following](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall13/cos226/assignments/collinear.html)

So I've never studied algorithms to this extent yet alone in java until a few months ago. I am trying to self-teach java and the more theoretical side of computer science. I want to prove myself(and to a certain gaslighting acquaintance of mine) that I can do it. However, I have reached a point where I'm too frustrated with myself to continue trying.

This is what I have so far:

```
package ColinearPt;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class BruteCollinearPoints {
    Point[] pointArray;
    ArrayList<PointSequence> pSeqArr = new ArrayList<>();

    public BruteCollinearPoints(Point[] points) {
        if (points == null)
            throw new NullPointerException();

        pointArray = points.clone();
        Arrays.sort(pointArray);

        for (int p = 0; p < pointArray.length - 3; p++) {
            for (int q = p + 1; q < pointArray.length - 2; q++) {
                for (int r = q + 1; r < pointArray.length - 1; r++) {
                    for (int s = r + 1; s < pointArray.length; s++) {
                        Point[] four = { pointArray[p], pointArray[q], pointArray[r], pointArray[s] };
                        PointSequence pseq = new PointSequence(four);
                        if (pseq.isCollinear()) {
                            pSeqArr.add(pseq);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //makes a defensive copy of the array of points

    public int numberOfPoints() {
        //returns the number of total points in the array

        return pointArray.length;
        //numberOfPoints();
    }

    public int numberOfSegments() {
        return pSeqArr.size();
        //returns the number of segments of length 4
    }

    public Iterable<PointSequence> segments() {
        //returns an iterable of segments of length 4
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //draws all 4 point segments in file
    }
}
```

I am especially confused with `segments()`, and since I don't know all the testing details, I'm not even sure what I am looking for. I've been reading up on Iterables but I'm still confused. I would really appreciate any tips on this particular project or even just how to study computer science on one's own.

Answer (score 1):

Because internally `Collection<E> extends Iterable<E>` so you can simply cast can collection to `Iterable`

Like below:

```
public Iterable<PointSequence> segments() {
    //returns an iterable of segments of length 4
    List<PointSequence> pSeqArr = new ArrayList<>();
    //add your logic
    return pSeqArr;
}
```